# Url that is relative to an ASP.NET MVC Area?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an Area like this:

```
Areas
    MiniBlog
        Controllers
        themes
            MyTheme
                Post.cshtml
        Views
            Blog
                Index.cshtml
```

Inside Index.cshtml I am using the following code:

```
@RenderPage("~/Areas/MiniBlog/themes/MyTheme/Post.cshtml", post);
```

I would rather do something like this:

```
@RenderPage(@currentArea + "themes/MyTheme/Post.cshtml", post);
```

**How do we get the path to the current area** so we can prevent hard coding it?

Comment: I'm not sure there is built-in property for area name. However you could make the constant returned by AreaRegistration.AreaName  public. But I think the common way is to have partial views in the dedicated folder so that we can just call RenderPartial("Post")

Comment: If you use T4MVC it's easy to get the urls. t4mvc.codeplex.com/‎

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a helper like this:

```
public static class ViewUtility
{
    private const string _areasRoot = "~/Areas/";

    public static string CurrentAreaRelativePath(string path)
    {
        var currentArea = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];

        return VirtualPathUtility.Combine(_areasRoot, currentArea + "/" + path);
    }
}

@RenderPage(ViewUtility.CurrentAreaRelativePath("themes/MyTheme/Post.cshtml"), post);
```